# Excel crashes when cross filtering

Tags: excel, vba, powerpivot, powerquery, pivot-chart

I have a read only 2013 workbook I use as a template tool with a data model going to 4 linked pivot charts with slicer enabled cross filtering.  When I select filter options on one slicer that filter out all options with data on another slicer my workbook crashes.

That is to say, slicer 1 has an option A, B, C and so on.

- Option A is related to a subset 1, 2 & 3 on slicer 2.
- Option B is related to a subset 4, 5 & 6 on slicer 2.

If slicer 2 has any data selected and I filter slicer 1 to preclude any portion of that selection my workbook crashes.

Things that didn’t work:

- I have rebuilt the charts, slicers and connections and still get the same issue.
- I built a very simple model in another workbook and could not reproduce the issue.
- I turned off events.
- I commented out my VBA.

If I am careful so select items that share a slicer 1 relationship from slicer 2 things seem to “work” but something is clearly broken here.

This condition seems to only occur when there is no overlap in related subsets to slicer 1 from slicer 2.  If option A has a subset 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. . . and option B has a 3, 4, 5 but no 1 or 2 I don’t get the issue, its only when all subsets are unique to the parent and selections don’t overlap (like no 5 in A = crash when 5 is unique to B and A is selected).  I couldn’t find any known issues related to this.

Event Viewer shows:

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 15.0.4797.1003, time stamp: 0x56bf05fc
    Faulting module name: msolap110_xl.DLL, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x55b0c5bf
```

My questions are:

1. Could “msolap110_xl.DLL” be the issue or is it more likely part of the symptom?
2. Have I mishandled the pivot charts, slicers or data model in some way to cause this?
3. Can it be fixed?

Relevant Programming:

```
Private Sub myReloadDataModel()
    If Range("myHasPath").Value = "True" Then
        MsgBox "You need to enter a path to a valid target location.", vbOKOnly, "Bad Path"
    Else
        myUser = MsgBox("Are you sure you want Reload the Data Model with any csv data located in the target path?", vbOKCancel, "3. Load Data Model")
        If myUser = vbOK Then

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Cursor = xlWait

            myTime01 = Time
            Sheets("Notes").Unprotect
            Sheets("2. Get Table").Unprotect
            ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
'            ActiveWorkbook.Model.Refresh
'            ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - myGetMasterSpan").Refresh
            x = ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - myGetMasterSpan").ModelTables.Item(1).RecordCount
            myTime02 = Time
            myTime03 = Format(myTime02 - myTime01, "HH:MM:SS")

            Sheets("2. Get Table").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
                , AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

            Application.Cursor = xlDefault
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True

            MsgBox Format(x, "#,##0") & " Records Loaded!" & vbNewLine _
                & vbNewLine _
                & "Total Update Time = " & myTime03, , "Update Completed"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Fales
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("2. Get Table").Unprotect

    Application.Run "mySlicerMagic"
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("LinkedTable_Table6").Refresh

    Set myChart04 = Sheets("Flow Errors").ChartObjects("Chart 4").Chart
        myChart04.ChartTitle.Text = Range("myErrorsTitle")
    With myChart04.Axes(xlValue)
        .MinimumScale = Range("myMin_Scale")
        .MaximumScale = Range("myMax_Scale")
    End With

    Set myChart05 = Sheets("Flow Errors").ChartObjects("Chart 5").Chart
        myChart05.ChartTitle.Text = Range("myErrorsTitle")
    With myChart05.Axes(xlValue)
        .MinimumScale = Range("myMin_Zoom")
        .MaximumScale = Range("myMax_Zoom")
    End With

        Application.Run "myChart5Format"

    Set thisPulseChart_02 = Sheets("Pulse Analyzer").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart
    With thisPulseChart_02
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Full Pulse Flow - " & Range("myErrorsTitle")
    End With
    With thisPulseChart_02.Axes(xlValue)
        .MaximumScale = Range("myMax_Scale") + 0.09
    End With

    Set thisPulseChart_03 = Sheets("Pulse Analyzer").ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart
    With thisPulseChart_03
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Raw Pulse Flow by Pulse- " & Range("myErrorsTitle")
    End With

        Application.Run "myChart3Format"

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This sub gets the selection range for me

```
Private Sub mySlicerMagic()
    On Error GoTo 100

    Set myX = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Pulse_Set").SlicerCacheLevels(1).SlicerItems

    For i = 1 To myX.Count
        If myX(i).Selected = True Then
            x = x + 1
            If x = 1 Then
                myItemName01 = myX(i).SourceName
            End If
            myItemName02 = myX(i).SourceName
        End If
    Next

    Range("myPulseRange")(1, 1) = myItemName01
    Range("myPulseRange")(2, 1) = myItemName02
100
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you check your Excel version number to make sure you have the latest fixes installed?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/gp/office-2013-365-update or  https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn789213(v=office.14)

Comment: The option "visually indicate items with no data" can become very costly on performance: http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-articles/53-excel/2567-excel-slicer-impact-on-query-performance

Comment: There was an update which I didn’t expect because I have updates to this Office product enabled and they should be downloaded and installed automatically.  That was obviously a bad assumption on my part. I was not prompted to reboot after the install but I did anyway. Unfortunately the update did not fix the issue.  I did however receive a new message to send information about the crash to Microsoft, which I did.  

Was running version: 15.0.4797.1003
Now running version: 15.0.4805.1003

Comment: My slicers are set to "Hide items with no data". I have tried both settings.  My thinking was that the difference in processing between these two settings was probably related to this glitch in some way, but it crashes either way.  I tried switching this again after updating to no avail.

Comment: @ZachH now that you are on the latest version if it still happens then opening a support case is the best way forward